# What is the .NET way to scope some of the logging to individual operations?

Tags: .net, logging

There's `ILogger.BeginScope`, but complex operations invoke many classes which have/take their own `ILogger<T>` instances. In fact large operations will often carry around their own logger factories.

For example, my app is doing video streaming. A single stream is a complex operation where user connects to endpoint and then the endpoint handler among other things would contact an `AudioSource` which writes its own logs to its own `ILogger` and a `VideoSource` which does the same.

Ideally I want to be able to see logs from both `AudioSource` and `VideoSource` for a given stream without `AudioSource` knowing anything about the stream ID.

E.g. (very simplified)

```cs
void Stream(string id) {
  var audio = new AudioSource(loggerFactory.CreateLogger<AudioSource>());
  var video = new VidoeSource(loggerFactory.CreateLogger<VideoSource>());

  Task.Run(() => {
    foreach(var frame in video)
      SendVideo(id, frame);
  });

  Task.Run(() => {
    foreach(var frame in audio)
      SendAudio(id, frame);
  });
}

class AudioSource {
  readonly ILogger<AudioSource> log;
  
  public IEnumerable<byte[]> GetEnumerable() {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      log.LogDebug("made frame {Index}", i);
      yield return new byte[42];
    }
  }
  
  ...
}
```

Here I want "made frame" messages in the final log to include the id from the `Stream` method

Comment: It is not very clear what exactly do you mean. Can you please expand a bit? Maybe add some code samples, ideally a [mre]? _"In fact large operations will often carry around their own logger factories."_ - TBH it is not a pattern I have seen often in production code (I would even say never). Also defining "operation" would be great also.

Comment: @GuruStron added an example

Comment: Will try to look into it tomorrow.